# Does GeoPandas .to_postgis remove my SRID when sending to PostGIS?

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas

I'm using the below code to insert the GeoPandas dataframe "df" into PostGIS but I keep getting the error that `Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (27700)`. The table in PostGIS has EPSG 27700 so there should be nothing wrong with it. Additionally, if I drop the PostGIS table and run the above code it runs and creates the table in PostGIS.

"df" is a geodataframe with CRS 27700

How can I get .to_postgis working?

```
df.to_postgis(
    con=engine,
    name="dbtable",
    if_exists ='append',
    dtype={'geoms': Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON', srid= 27700)}
)
```

Comment: You mentioned that "df" is a geodataframe with CRS 27700 but what `df.crs.to_epsg()` does return? Also what does `SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'dbtable', 'your_geom_name');` on the PostGIS side? There is clearly a mismatch between Pandas geometry SRID and PostGIS destination table SRID from the message `Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (27700)`. Now the question is on which side, hence my questions.

Comment: thanks @ThomasG77. The df.crs.to_epsg() is 27700 and SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'dbtable', 'your_geom_name'); is also 27700, hence my confusion where the mismatch is originating from.

Comment: I also tried dropping the table entirely from postgis and inserting df as a new table by making .to_postgis(if_exists = 'replace'), but the same error is encountered.

Comment: What does `SELECT ST_SRID(your_geom_name) FROM dbtable` returns when you do what you mentioned e.g "Additionally, if I drop the PostGIS table and run the above code it runs and creates the table in PostGIS". Also where does your `Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON', srid= 27700)`. What import do you do in your Python code to get `Geometry` function (I need to know, so I can look in the corresponding library API)

Comment: Does `Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON', srid=27700)` instead of `Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON', srid= 27700)` is better (no space between `srid=` and `27700`?